# How do I renew my DHCP lease?

Tags: networking

Short of rebooting, how can I release and renew my DHCP lease? It would be useful to know a GUI and terminal method.

I'd especially like to know if there is a means to do this without requiring admin privileges.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the network drop-down selector of the system tray you can press the network you are already connected to. This will make [NetworkManager](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager) ask for a new lease from a DHCP server.

[image: NetworkManager tray screenshot]

This also works for wired networks, but I don't think it works for PPP connections (mobile broadband).

Answer (score 70):

To renew your dhcp lease at the terminal:

```
sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient
```

Comment: I think `sudo service networking restart` is a better way to go. What you suggest didn't work for me on an 11.10 box with dhclient3. Instead, I ended up with *two* DHCP clients running: one `dhclient3` and one `dhclient`. See http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1868368

Comment: @AdamMonsen Does restarting the networking service actually work with NetworkManager?

Comment: @AdamMonsen restarting networking does not seem to renew the dhcp lease for me

Comment: `sudo service network-manager restart` in Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit desktop appears to properly restart network stuff and renew my DCHP lease. (From http://askubuntu.com/a/230751/2273 )

Comment: Useful to know for debugging: on Ubuntu 14.04 `sudo service network-manager restart` didn't completely renew IP lease from DHCP. It just send a DHCP `Request` packet instead of a `Discover`. If you just want to renew your lease it's enough, but if you are debugging DHCP you want to use the original solution.

Comment: Restarting networking isn't a good way to go.  I'm trying to do this on a remote machine. I will lose my access if I cut its networking. If it doesn't come back, I'm screwed.  No, blowing off all your network routes and taking the interface down is not a good solution to the problem "I want to renew a DHCP lease", just like getting out the shot gun is not a good solution to getting rid of a cockroach.

Comment: how to stop  sudo dhclient command... event ctrl + c stoped it... =(

Comment: This option has the advantage, that it only resets dhcp, without stopping/reinitiating the network connection. All the other answers do a complete network reconfiguration, what is unneeded in the question.

Answer (score 51):

In my case I had to specify which card to renew:

*Note: you might want to join the two on one line, as otherwise you might lose the remote connection you're on after the first!*

First release the current IP address:

```
sudo dhclient -r eth0
```

then renew the IP address

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

.. or do them together to avoid losing connection:

```
sudo dhclient -r eth0 && sudo dhclient eth0
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you have more than one interface.

Comment: Better:  
Join the commands with AND -  
`sudo dhclient -r enp7s0 && sudo dhclient enp7s0` (replace with your eth network device)

Comment: Please edit this answer to join these together, I just got kicked off a remote box trying these separately.

Comment: Worked for me in Ubuntu server 18.04

Comment: for me, the change of IP was effective only after running `netplan apply`. Before, `dhclient` was showing a new IP, but it wasn't used

Answer (score 15):

If you're on a `systemd` based-version of Ubuntu without a GUI (i.e. server version) then this is the way to renew the DHCP lease:

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd
```

Note: If you're connected via the interface whose DHCP lease you're renewing you may get disconnected, unless you're connected via a statically configured interface or the console.

Comment: I was testing this with `dhcpdump` listening on other terminal. Didn't seem to work, only the `dhclient` way.

Comment: If your machine is using `dhclient` then you would use that. In newer versions of Ubuntu dhclient is not used and instead the DHCP client in `system-networkd` is used.

Answer (score 11):

This works on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

When I do that, Network Manager asks for a new DHCP lease.

I prefer this to manually (re)starting `dhclient` because I've had problems by stale dhclient processes (ones not managed by Network Manager) spontaneously and incorrectly reconfiguring my network settings at random points when it's least convenient.

Comment: Still relevant on Ubuntu 16.04. `dhclient -r` just silently does nothing with a successful exit code otherwise. :-(

Comment: This worked fine on 18.04!

Answer (score 9):

Maverick comes with `nmcli`, a command line interface to the network manager.

I can't see a simple way of telling it to renew a lease, but running:

```
nmcli con
```

Gets you a connection list, and running:

```
nmcli con down id 'Connection Name'
nmcli con up id 'Connection Name'
```

Takes the connection down and back up. It may be possible to do something similar with the device instead.

The connection list seems to include all connections, so this will probably work with PPTP and VPN connections too.

Comment: My DHCP server still shows the lease there... (I'm trying to force a release to make a static assignment take effect)

Answer (score 2):

How you renew the DHCP lease ***depends on the DHCP client the system is using***.

Since 16.04, Ubuntu has used Netplan- a high-level abstraction- to set the networking gears in the `renderer:` directive in the config file `/etc/netplan/fileName.yaml`.

- Where `renderer: NetworkManager`, restart NetworkManager to renew the lease

  ```
  sudo service network-manager restart
  ```
- Where `renderer: networkd`, then dhclient is used to renew the lease

  ```
  sudo dhclient -r; sudo dhclient
  ```

As a general rule *at the time of this writing*:

- **Server versions** of Ubuntu use `systemd-networkd` to control the networking in netplan
- **Desktop versions** of Ubuntu use NetworkManager.

Obviously if you're a SysAdmin handling systems others have implemented, they could have changed the value of `renderer` to change the default, so worth checking the netplan config file to validate which system is authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

Having just upgraded to Maverick Meerkat Beta 1, something broke in my standard, vanilla eth0 configuration which I've not debugged yet. The quick and dirty [workaround has been](http://linux.die.net/man/8/dhclient)

```
sudo dhclient
```

which notices that there was a (possibly dead) client already and obtains a new lease:

```
There is already a pid file /var/run/dhclient.pid with pid 2436
killed old client process, removed PID file
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client V3.1.3
Listening on LPF/eth0/00:1a:92:24:9c:85
Sending on   LPF/eth0/00:1a:92:24:9c:85
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on vboxnet0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3
DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.2.2 on eth0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
DHCPACK of 192.168.2.2 from 192.168.2.1
bound to 192.168.2.2 -- renewal in 118389830 seconds.
```

This isn't a fix, just a hack. I'll follow-up when I figure what went bad.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking this specific capability via `nmcli`, I believe the best CLI solution is to release and kill the dhclient instance managed by NetworkManager, rather than starting a new one. NM will then bring it back up again automatically, avoiding having to restart the entire NM infrastructure.

```
sudo dhclient -v -r -pf /run/sendsigs.omit.d/network-manager.dhclient-eth0.pid
```

- `-v` - make verbose
- `-r` - release and shut down
- `-pf` - pid file of NM's instance

Answer (score 0):

You can release dhcp or dhcpv6 by picking dhclient-xxxx.lease or dhclient6-xxxx.lease

ex.

```
sudo dhclient -lf
/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-8c3bf569-fa6e-33d7-becb-a4095f8137c0-eth1.lease
-r -v eth1
```

```
sudo dhclient -6 -lf 
/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient6-6657588-f38e-45fd-b88d-6145401fae5e-eth1.lease
-r -v eth1
```