# Renew DHCP lease in systemd-networkd

Tags: networking, 18.04, dhcp, systemd-networkd

I have my `eth0` interface configured for DHCPv4 via `netplan`:

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: true
            optional: true
```

How do I tell `systemd-networkd` to renew my DHCP lease? I know with `dhclient` it's as simple as `dhclient -r eth0 && dhclient eth0`, as explained in many other answers on this site, but how do I do it for `systemd-networkd`?

I'm in Ubuntu 18.04 Server.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Starting](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/205013c8002aacd142264e9b4560e86b0ba05830/NEWS#L2233) from systemd version 244, you can renew DHCP lease in systemd-networkd with the following command:

```
networkctl renew DEVICES...
```

Ubuntu 20.04 shipped with systemd 245.4 and is the first version of Ubuntu where this command is available.

Comment: Nice find! I'm trying to find out which version of Ubuntu that systemd 244 is first included in, so we can add that to your answer. Unfortunately, the release notes don't seem to specify...

Comment: You can find this information well and conveniently formatted [here](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=ubuntu).
Ubuntu 20.04 is the oldest release with systemd >244.

Answer (score 6):

I found a freedesktop.org [mailing list post](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-August/022662.html) from Tom Gundersen in August 2014 that answers my question, at least as of the time it was written:

> > Is there a way to force a DHCPv4 release/renew with systemd-networkd?
>
> We don't currently allow dynamic interaction with networkd, but you
>   can force renew the release by either restarting networkd or
>   unplugging/replugging the cable (or switching your wifi off/on if
>   that's what you are using).
>
> -t

So apparently if you do one of these two things, `systemd-networkd` will renew your DHCP lease.

Comment: Did it work for you? [This seems right](https://askubuntu.com/a/1047656/349837), but `systemctl restart systemd-networkd` didn't help, only `dhclient -v -r eth0; dhclient -v eth0` (testing with `dhcpdump -i eth0` on other terminal).

Comment: @PabloA If you're using `systemd-networkd`, then you don't want to use `dhclient`...it will interfere with `systemd-networkd`. Or, perhaps more accurately, `systemd-networkd` will probably interfere with your use of `dhclient` at some point. I'm not 100% sure that it worked, as I didn't really look that closely in my router's webpage after running the command, but I assume it did since I see that in multiple other answers on this site that that's the correct way to do it for `systemd-networkd`.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that if you do a restart on `systemd-networkd`, it ignores the previous lease and just starts over with a clean request.

If you're also using a `dhcpd` that does a ping check you end up with a second.  That might be an interaction with how I've set up the network config.  We use *Critical* because otherwise `systemd-network` sends a `DHCPRELEASE` on shutdown and, most critically, *also forgets the lease it had before*.  So rebooting two `systemd-networkd` servers at the same time has a very high chance of both of them losing their IP addresses.

I'm unsure what the conditions that cause this to happen are, however, I've found that if you send a `-HUP` to `systemd-networkd`, and then *start* the service (not restart) it will use the leases that are in `/var/run/systemd/netif` as you would expect.

Comment: What do you mean when you write *we use Critical*? I would like not to send `DHCPRELEASE` as well when restarting `systemd-networkd`