# When does ubuntu initiate a DHCP lease renewal?

Tags: networking, 20.04, dhcp, ip, ip-address

After doing some research. I found out that some DHCP clients initiate a lease renew when 50% of the lease time has elapsed. And I need to know if this is valid for ubuntu 20 and later DHCP clients. I tried to look around and found out how to manually renew. But I need to know how the automatic lease renewal works.

An example where the 50% is mentioned is [Here](https://community.spiceworks.com/t/how-do-dhcp-reservations-renew/104363#:%7E:text=DHCP%20clients%20will%20try%20to,from%20any%20available%20DHCP%20server.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I renew my DHCP lease?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4014/how-do-i-renew-my-dhcp-lease)

Comment: @graham not really. I know how to manually renew it. I need to know how frequent does the client renew by default

Comment: My test 24.04 VM is being granted a lease time of 24 hours from my DHCP server. It is renewing every 12 hours or at 50%.

Comment: @DougSmythies OH Thanks! That is great to know and I will use this information. just hoping someone could provide me with maybe documentation of any official resource to make sure I'm doing the right thing.